# Accessing same shapefile for different users via SharePoint in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgs, qgz, sharepoint

We are currently migrating our files and data to SharePoint. Currently, we are using our file system with a path structure like this:
`Z:\_Maps\Cities\Project1.qgz` with a shapefile (*.shz*) which will be used as layers for different projects.

Our new SharePoint-Structure corresponds with the Username: `C:\Users\sven\MMA/_Maps\Cities\Project1.qgz`

QGIS now has a problem finding the shapefile when different users try to access the project. Do you know how to use/share projects/shapefiles with different users with SharePoint?

Comment: We had a similar transition where I work and it was seamless. By default, QGIS should be accessing files using relative file paths (i.e. relative to the .qgz file location).

The Relative file path option can be set per project under Project > Properties > General and under General Settings, Save Paths. The default option for new projects can be set under Settings > Options > General and scroll down to find the Default paths option. 

Can you check this first? Otherwise perhaps a screenshot of the folder structure and error message (censor out company name, file name etc) would help

Answer (score 1):

To do so, I used onedrive sync, and QGIS considers it at as standard folder.
All user will have to sync to the same directory, which is a bit of a problem.

Could not directly open from sharepoint.